# Web scraping: .find doesn't find string in line of web page

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am writing my first python program and hope that you can help me with my current problem.

I try to extract data from a website and I checked the source of the page where a certain string (lets say "thisstring") is part of a line.

**In the HTML-code the string is listed under :**

```
<script>
      anotherstring;
      thisstring = {...};
```

**My current code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
page = requests.get('www.somewebadress.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
lines = soup.find_all('script')

x = 0 #counter for script which returns the correct number of <script> parts in the html-code

for line in lines:
    x = x + 1
    txt = line.find('thisstring') #didnt work with "thisstring" either
    if txt == None:
        print("not found")
    else:
        print("found")
    
print(x)
```

I tried a lot different solutions I found in the www but "thisstring" is never found even if python printed it out with print(line).
I think it is quite simple but I tried the whole day to find the correct code.

Does anyone have an idea?

I found several code samples in stackoverflow and other python tutorials for web scraping but non of these worked. I use Spyder. Could this be a problem?

Comment: Do you want to extract the content of `{...}` from the HTML source ?

Comment: Exactly. "Thisstring" is like my key-variable as it is available in all sub pages I want to loop through. And the part behind "thisstring =" contains the wanted information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments you can use `re` module to extract the variable:

```py
import re

html_text = """\
<html>
<script>
    otherscript;
</script>

<script>
      anotherstring;
      thisstring = {"data1": 1, "data2": 2};
</script>
</html>"""

# or:
# html_text = requests.get(...).text

data = re.search(r"thisstring = (\{.*\});", html_text).group(1)
print(data)
```

Prints:

```json
{"data1": 1, "data2": 2}
```

---

Then you can use `ast.literal_eval`, `json` or `js2py` to convert the string to python object:

```
import json

data = json.loads(data)
print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort.
Unfortunately, my output is different:

  File "path", line 21, in <module>
    data = re.search("*window.ultimas_this_product = {*};", html_text).group(1)

  File "path", line 201, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)

{...some more lines like those above...}

  File "path", line 669, in _parse
    raise source.error("nothing to repeat",

error: nothing to repeat

Do you know what does this mean?

Comment: @MyKa You have malformed regex pattern. Try `data = re.search(r"window\.ultimas_this_product = (\{.*\});", html_text).group(1)`

Comment: Haha I am so sorry. I thought the r"-part was a typo and that I have to adapt this part (\{.*\}) to the actual string which doesn't have () before {}. Thank you so much. The code now works and prints out the correct line :) :)